# How to give access for IBM Cloud for Domain Name Services and Cloud Internet Services to account users?

Tags: authorization, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-iam

How to give access to my team mate on IBM Cloud account on the resources, Domain Registration Service and Internet Services resource?

The admin wants add privileges. But when he looks the list, can not find the Domain Registration and internet services. The users are already in the IBM Cloud account.

Comment: Please add details to your question: Are they already in the account? Do they need specific privileges (read, write, admin, ...)?

Comment: Yes they are already in the account. I need admin priveliges on the services.

Comment: Do they need privileges or you? Someone with the right set of privileges needs to grant them. It depends on whether they can already use, e.g., the resource group and if access groups etc. are involved.

Comment: The admin wants add privileges. But when he looks the list, can not find the Domain Registration and internet services. I am asking on his behalf,  how he can give these to these resources to me

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish that with IBM Cloud IAM (Identity and Access Management), including granting the permissions directly to the users in questions or [creating an access group](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-groups&interface=ui) with the privileges first and adding the users to that group (best practice).

- [DNS Services](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-iam-service-roles-actions) has the listed roles including Administrator
- [Cloud Internet Services](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-iam-service-roles-actions#cloud-internet-services) has a Manager service role

So your admin would

1. create an access group
2. add the privileges for DNS Services and CIS to it as policies
3. would need to make sure that privileges on the resource group to see the service instances are added
4. add the users to the access group.

Thereafter, you should have access.